# Calculating $(I-A^t(AA^t)^{-1}A)(3,0)^t$ where $A=(0 \ -1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to do the following multiplication of matrices:

$$(I-A^t(AA^t)^{-1}A)(3,0)^t$$

Where $A=(0 \ -1)$. The problem is that I think the dimensions don't match. For example, $AA^t = 1$. What is $(1)^{-1}$? I think that the inverse of a matrix $a$ is a matrix $b$ such that $ba=I$. So the inverse of $(1)$ would be a matrix such $a$ that $(a)(1) = (1)$ (where $(1)$ is the identity of order $1$), so we get $a=(1)$ and the multiplicaiton becomes

$$(I-(0 \ -1) ^t(1)(0\ -1))(3,0)^t = (I-(0 \ -1) ^t(0\ -1))(3,0)^t$$

Is it right? If yes, how to do $(0 \ -1) ^t(0\ -1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of a $1\times 2$ matrix and a $2\times 1$ matrix is just a number (a $1 \times 1$ matrix). So $AA^t$ is the number $1$ and your computation is ok. The product of a $2 \times 1$ matrix and a $1 \times 2$ matrix is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. You have
$$A^tA =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
0& -1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$